# How to use variables/strings as SQLITE3 table name

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
("CREATE TABLE %s AS (SELECT * FROM anime WHERE color = %s" % (userid, color))
```

I am trying to use %s but I get the error `RuntimeError: near "1": syntax error`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be missing a parenthesis in your SQL query.

```
("CREATE TABLE %s AS (SELECT * FROM anime WHERE color = %s)" % (userid, color))
```

Comment: You're right! Unfortunately, I still get the same error message, is there anything else that looks wrong to you?

Comment: I tried running a similar query on my own end, and it actually doesn't look like I even need the parentheses in the first place (adding them results in the `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error` error). Try just removing the parentheses and see what happens.